# calculating the confidence intervals between two approaches

Tags: math, video-processing, confidence-interval

I'm trying to do something like what has mentioned in "VSUMM" article.
There are 5 approaches which i want to compare their results with mine. i do compare all of them in a table by calculating the CUS(a) i.e mean accuracy rate and CUS(e) i.e mean error rate for each of them.(it's a video summarization problem and each approaches has got their summeries for 50 videos. this summeries has been compared with five user summeries and then the CUS(a) and CUS(e) are calculated by these reults)
now i should calculate the confidence intervals(with the confidence of 98%) of each of those approaches with mine
i surf the web and find long articles about confidence intervals but i did not really understand any thing!?
what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally find the answer:
For calculating the confidence intervals between your approach and other approaches you should have the results of your algorithm and those approaches for sure. then you can calculate mean of these data and their Standard deviation. then you could use the confidence intervals formula:
(amean-bmean) +/- z(1-a/2)*sqrt((stda^2/n1)+(stdb^2/n2)
which stda is Standard deviation of a
n1 the number of data in first group
amean=the mean value of the first group, i.e the mean of results of first approach